# Assign the element name to a variable?

Tags: jquery

So this is my example HTML:

```
<div name="John Doe"></div>
```

**Note**: I know all about ID's and classes in CSS. I am fully aware they exist. But in this case I'm wondering what to do when it's the name value I'm trying to work with.

Basically, how do I save the name of the div, in this case "John Doe" to a variable?

I can successfully access it with the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[name="John Doe"]').click(function(){

    Do something;

};
```

Comment: Pretty sure element names can't have spaces.

Comment: @elclanrs, no, he means the attribute, not the element itself. Though if you already knew it was "John Doe" I don't know why you'd need to, but....

Comment: ^ Yeah I noticed... Btw, is `name` a valid attribute for a `div`?

Comment: @elclanrs As per my understanding, `name` is explicitly given to the input elements which will be used when you do a form submit. `name` attribute in div is semantically not proper..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `data` attributes for this

HTML:

```
<div data-name="John Doe">...</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('div[data-name="John Doe"]').on('click', function() {
        var myNameVar = $(this).data('name'); // Here is your variable.
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tatB/

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a space in the attribute name, but this will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[name="John Doe"]').click(function(){
        var divname = $(this).attr("name");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Element names cannot contain spaces. I took the liberty of adding an underscore:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[name="John_Doe"]').click(function(){
        var divAttrName = $(this).attr('name').replace('_', ' ');;
    });
};
```